# Auto filled search box

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code which shows a marker from my current location and sets the coordinates into the page title, buy now I want to add a search box for adresses but I need that the text of the search box changes to the corresponding coordinates when the markes is draged. and i have no idea hot to do that

here is my code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

    #map_canvas{
        height:800px;
        width:800px;
    }   
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script>        
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
      var marker, map;

      function initialize(position ) {
var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: coords,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), 
            mapOptions);

window.document.title= new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coords ,
            map: map,
            draggable:true
        });



        google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'dragend', function(evt){
       window.document.title = evt.latLng.lat() + ',' + evt.latLng.lng() ;
});     
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what search box? a html input?

Comment: yes, I know i can preset an initial adress but i want to link it to the coordinates from the marker

Comment: my question is what/where is your search box? I don't see any in your html?

Comment: I haven,t placed it jet, since i dont know how to use it properly

Answer (score -1):

[Test this](https://jsfiddle.net/tkjs6evt/1/), and tell me what you think of it

I used the `document.getElementById()` to select the search_box, and changed its `innerHTML`.

I slightly modified your event listener

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'dragend', function(evt){
    var coordinates = {lat: evt.latLng.lat(), lng: evt.latLng.lng()};

   window.document.title = coordinates.lat + ',' + coordinates.lng ;
   document.getElementById('search_box').innerHTML = coordinates.lat + ',' + coordinates.lng ;
});
```

and I added a div with an id of `search_box` in your HTML.

Comment: I had a little error in my variable declaration, it is now fixed

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10838740)

Comment: Which I did, I said I added a selector and changed its content via `innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan ,but so far as I beeb able to research,the searchbox actually can not be defined as a div,so i used a text box instead an changed its "value" instead "innerHTML" google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'dragend', function(evt){
    var coordinates = {lat: evt.latLng.lat(), lng: evt.latLng.lng()};

   window.document.title = coordinates.lat + ',' + coordinates.lng ;
   document.getElementById('text_box').value = coordinates.lat + ',' + coordinates.lng ;

Comment: Good job, so my answer worked well with a little change div to input?